# Javascript way to list available plugins for IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, browser

Is there a quick way to get a list in JavaScript of the available Active X plugins?

I need to do a test to see if a plugin has been installed before I actually try to run it.

In effect I want to create a page that says 'Plugin Installed and properly Working' or have it fail gracefully.

I'm not sure how to have it fail gracefully if the plugin is not available.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just `try` it.

```
try {
  var plugin = new ActiveXObject('SomeActiveX');
} catch (e) {
  alert("Error"); // Or some other error code
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  I would prefer to be able to see if it exists without actually having to instantiate is.  But it looks like it is the only way.

Comment: Correct.  In IE, there is no way to check for an addons existence without trying to use it.

Answer (score 2):

The [object](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_object.asp) tag will display whatever is inside it if the object cannot be instantiated:

```
<object ...>
 <p>
 So sorry, you need to install the object.  Get it <a href="...">here</a>.
 </p>
</object>
```

So, graceful failure is built-in and you don't need to use script at all.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this script can help

```
function detectPlugin() {
// allow for multiple checks in a single pass
var daPlugins = detectPlugin.arguments;

// consider pluginFound to be false until proven true
var pluginFound = false;

// if plugins array is there and not fake
if (navigator.plugins && navigator.plugins.length > 0) {
var pluginsArrayLength = navigator.plugins.length;

// for each plugin...
for (pluginsArrayCounter=0; pluginsArrayCounter < pluginsArrayLength; pluginsArrayCounter++ ) {

    // loop through all desired names and check each against the current plugin name
    var numFound = 0;
    for(namesCounter=0; namesCounter < daPlugins.length; namesCounter++) {

    // if desired plugin name is found in either plugin name or description
    if( (navigator.plugins[pluginsArrayCounter].name.indexOf(daPlugins[namesCounter]) >= 0) || 
        (navigator.plugins[pluginsArrayCounter].description.indexOf(daPlugins[namesCounter]) >= 0) ) {
        // this name was found
        numFound++;
    }   
    }
    // now that we have checked all the required names against this one plugin,
    // if the number we found matches the total number provided then we were successful
    if(numFound == daPlugins.length) {
    pluginFound = true;
    // if we've found the plugin, we can stop looking through at the rest of the plugins
    break;
    }
}
}
return pluginFound;} // detectPlugin
```

Call it using this for exemple

```
pluginFound = detectPlugin('Shockwave','Flash');
```

Comment: Does this work in IE8?  I was playing around with the navigator object earlier and the length of plugins was zero.

Comment: It seems to be working because this page http://www.unibanco.com.br/vste/_exc/_hom/index.asp is using the script with no problems.

Comment: Turns out that the plugins array is not populated in Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

For Internet Explorer 11 you can use ***navigator.plugins*** JS API, but you need to add apropriate registrey keys in order for IE11 to detect it:

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\NavigatorPluginsList
```

or for 64bit

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\NavigatorPluginsList
```

e.g. for plugin with Name "ABC" and mime type "application/abc" :

- add key *HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432\Microsoft\Internet
  Explorer\NavigatorPluginsList\ABC*
- create subkey for each custom MIME
  type supported by the plugin, using the MIME type value as the name
  of the subkey e.g. "application/abc"

Then checking for the plugin existence is done using this code:

```
var plugin = navigator.plugins["<your plugin activex id>"];
if(plugin) {
  //plugin detected
} else {
  //plugin not found
}
```

More on this here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn423948(v=vs.85).aspx