# How to list plugins in IE using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have searched a lot but only found outdated sources on how to list the plugins used in Internet explorer client side using Javascript.

Does anyone know of a code that works and identifies the plugins?

This is a website that detects plugins on IE https://panopticlick.eff.org/index.php?action=log&js=yes

I am using this code below for other browsers:

```
navigator.plugins.refresh(false);

var numPlugins = navigator.plugins.length;
var a = '';

for (var i = 0; i < numPlugins; i++) {
    var plugin = navigator.plugins[i];

    if (plugin) {
        a += plugin.name + plugin.filename;
    }
}
```

Comment: @DanielA.White yes it does, they match manually the plugins from the code

Comment: @DanielA.White I have updated my question with a link. Open it in IE

Comment: i do see it now - it is working for me in ie.

Comment: If it can be useful there is a way to [detect a specific plugin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/917148/javascript-way-to-list-available-plugins-for-ie)

Comment: ie11 does have `navigator.plugins`.

Comment: You can simply check the source code of [Panopticlick](https://panopticlick.eff.org/resources/fetch_whorls.js). For IE it uses [PluginDetect](http://www.pinlady.net/PluginDetect/).

Answer (score -1):

This may help:

```
try {
  var plugin = new ActiveXObject('SomeActiveX');
} catch (e) {
  alert("Error");
}
```